# Popup window Error with spinner

Tags: android, spinner, popupwindow

I'm making a program that when you give a button a popup window appears with two spinners, but I get a problem when I try to initialize these spinners ... and do not know why.

my popup window:

```
public void añadirRegistro(View v){

     showPopup(leer_registros.this);
}
private void showPopup(final Activity context) {

       Spinner eleccionIP,eleccionRegistro;
       borrar_datos BorrarDatos = new borrar_datos ();
       // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
       RelativeLayout viewGroup = (RelativeLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_elegir_registros, viewGroup);
       eleccionIP = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.popupIP);
       eleccionRegistro = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.popupRegistro);



       /*Cursor cur=BorrarDatos.obtenerIP();
       BorrarDatos.rellenarSpinner(cur,eleccionIP);*/


       final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
       popup.setContentView(layout);
       popup.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       popup.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       popup.setFocusable(true);

       popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 200, 200);


       ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> (context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

      adapter.add("item 1");
      adapter.add("item 2");
      eleccionIP.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

The error I get is that pressing the spinner to see the items I keep on giving me an error that leaves the compiler, and not that ....

Answer (score 0):

> when you give a button a popup window appears with two spinners

means Spinner is inside Popup Window so use `layout` instance for initializing Spinners as:

```
......
View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_elegir_registros, viewGroup);
eleccionIP = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.popupIP);
eleccionRegistro = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.popupRegistro);
```

Comment: if it was that! , Thank you very much for real =).

Now I have new problem, which is that if I click on the spinner to see the other items that have the spinner I get error, why?

Comment: @Isma9 : please update your latest code and logcat results in question to get more help from us

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in to your spinner xml

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```